# Binding DataGrid in C# to MySQL - MySQL connection problems

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have simple program, trying to display a MySQL table in a WPF / C# application. Now, for some reason, I seem to be having problem with the connection, and I can't quite figure out what it is.

My main window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Szuper adatbázisfeltöltő" Height="267.143" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="236" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
            <TabItem Header="Adatbázis">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="119" Width="441"/>
                    <Button Content="Új rekord" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                    <Button Content="Frissítés" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                    <Button Content="Törlés" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Adminisztráció">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What happens when I run the program:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UpdateGrid();
}

public void UpdateGrid()
{
  //  dataGrid1.DataContext = Class1.getTable().DefaultView;
    //dataGrid1.SelectedValuePath = "index";
}
```

}

And where the magic is supposed to happen:

```
   class Class1
    {
        static String str = "Server=http://mysql10.000webhost.com;Database=a2116591_adat;Uid=a2116591_tkis;Pwd=zseton22";
        static MySqlConnection con = null;

        public static DataTable getTable()
        {

            //MySqlDataReader Object
            MySqlDataReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                con = new MySqlConnection(str);
                con.Open(); //open the connection
                //We will need to SELECT all or some columns in the table
                //via this command
                String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM adat";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //execute the reader
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (MySqlException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Close(); //close the connection

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried varying around the connection string, but to no avail and I am kind of stuck.

Comment: Just to clarify, the error happens at Line 26 of Class1 - at con.Open();

Comment: If the problem is about the database connection then phrase your question around that and remove everything else. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. It just says: A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
Error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Answer (score 1):

```
  class Class1
   {
       static String str = "your connection string";
      static MySqlConnection con = null;

    public static DataSet getTable()
    {

        //MySqlDataReader Object
        MySqlDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            con = new MySqlConnection(str);
            con.Open(); //open the connection
            //We will need to SELECT all or some columns in the table
            //via this command
            String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM adat";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet  ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "R");
        con.Close();
        return ds;


        }
        catch (MySqlException err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close(); //close the connection

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
    public MainWindow()
  {
  InitializeComponent();
   UpdateGrid();
  } 

 public void UpdateGrid()
{
   dataGrid1.DataMember = "R";
        dataGrid1.DataSource = class1.gettable();
}
```

Comment: if there is no error in your Con.open() this code works fine else youm have to lookin for your connection string

Comment: ye, I think it's something with the connection string, but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: Its simple get verified with your connection string

Comment: Try to use Trusted_Connection=True;